# What causes the error in App Delegate: Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource?

Tags: swift, xcode

I think error stems from elsewhere, not AppDelegate.
So, in a viewcontroller type file (class homepage) I want to fetch info from firebase and display. After finishing that section of code, App delegate gives an error.

I've removed the UITableViewDataSource from AppDelegate, then it runs, but doesn't display Firebase info.

```
class homepage: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var people = [Userx]()

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!


    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
    }

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]

        cell.lblName.text = person.Education
        cell.lblgenre.text = person.WhatIamConsideringBuying

        return cell

    }

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

 override func viewDidLoad() {

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(signOut))

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("Education").observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in

        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            self.people.removeAll()
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"]
                let peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying = peopleObject?["WhatIamConsideringBuying"]
                let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]
                let people = Userx(Education: peopleEducation as! String?, WhatIamConsideringBuying: peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying as! String?, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts as AnyObject)
                    self.people.append(people)

            }
            self.table.reloadData()

        }

    })


///this is different file code for class ViewControllerTableViewCell

class ViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblgenre: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Since the error may be in storyboard, the path of homepage is:Homepage Scene - Homepage - Table - Cell - Content View - label 1 and label 2. DataSource and Delegate from Table is connected to Homepage via Outlets.

I just want the error in AppDelegate to disappear so that data can be fetched from firebase.

Here is App Delegate code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()


            return true
}


func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

Database Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh0LK.jpg

Comment: Post the code of your AppDelegate if the error says something is wrong there

Comment: Ok, will add now. I am pretty sure error is not there though as I never changed it.

Comment: You don't control a table with AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks. I removed both table references there. It works (like mentioned in the question), but then no data gets fetched from Firebase.

Comment: I think the error may have something to do with not having textfield outlets in homepage. However adding them makes error: Illegal Configuration. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write this code in your viewDidLoad() method

```
   table.dataSource = self
   table.delegate = self
```

And update your code in cellForRowAt

```
     public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

       if let person = people[indexPath.row] {
              cell.lblName.text = person.Education
             cell.lblgenre.text = person.WhatIamConsideringBuying
       }

      return cell

 }
```

To Prevent App from crash

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(signOut))

super.viewDidLoad()

let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("Education").observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in

    if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
        self.people.removeAll()
        for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"]
            let peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying = peopleObject?["WhatIamConsideringBuying"]
            let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]

     if let peopleEducation =  peopleEducation as? String {
        if let whatIAmConsideringBuying = peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying as? String? {
          if let photoPosts = photoPost as? AnyObject {
            let people = Userx(Education: peopleEducation, WhatIamConsideringBuying: whatIAmConsideringBuying, PhotoPosts: photoPosts)
              self.people.append(people)
    }
   }
 }


}
        self.table.reloadData()

    }

})
```

Comment: Where do you find viewDidLoad in AppDelegate?

Comment: I am saying for viewController viewDidLoad method. I think error occurs because it does not make tableView delegate to controller

Comment: I think the error may have something to do with not having textfield outlets in homepage. However adding them makes error: Illegal Configuration. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Comment: There is no need of outlets in homepage if they have in ViewControllerTableViewCell .

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I know what's wrong. (no idea how to fix though). I think it has to do with how the firebase Database is structured. It is structured like this: 
Education >
>>>> userkey x…p : “”
>>>> userkey y…….: “”
PhotoPost
>>>> userkey x…p: “”
>>>> userkey y…….: “”
 
I think my code is written so that the children would be where the user keys are in the database at the moment. Do you agree?

Comment: It's hard to properly describe the database structure in comment. I have added it in a link in the question.

Comment: Yes database structure is the main problem . According to your written code PhotoPost is the child of Education but as structure seems PhotoPost is not a child . But according to some good practices your code should be written like if data unable to fetch from server your app should not crashed . So to prevent crash does not forecast and make it optional . I am editing my answer to show you to to prevent from crash.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the database structure last night and it work.